# Creating a slider that instead of setting, increases/decreases a variable

Tags: dynamic

**The objective:**
Create a slider that, when displaced from the center, increases-decreases the value of another variable at a rate proportional to the displacement.

So, I create a slider that automatically comes back to the center

```
Slider[Dynamic[var, {(var = #) &, (var = 0.) &}], {-1, 1}]
```

Now I want a second variable to be dynamically increased/decreased when `var!=0.`

**My ideas are:**

1. insert in the previous dynamic, something that does the updating
2. use an animator with its speed set by `var` when `var!=0.` that updates the value

**Problems with the above:**

1. How to control the speed of the updating given that I can't know for sure the intervals in which `val` will be updated, and `UpdateIntervals` sets an upper bound?
2. How to make it work without it showing in the screen?

Any other alternatives are welcome (ideally I'd like an elegant solution).

Comment: @R.M, hope this pings you. Heike's answer shows my intentions clearly. Now that `Dynamic[y, {y=g[x]}]` I wasn't aware of. I thought the second argument was supposed to be a function and that they only made sense when the dynamic was "being set by a control". What does it do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you could do something like this,

```
var = 0.; p = 0.; interval = .2;
task = RunScheduledTask[p += var, interval];
{Slider[Dynamic[var, {(var = #) &, (var = 0.) &}], {-1, 1}], Dynamic[p]}
```

The downside is that rather than increasing `p` by a fixed amount at variable time intervals, this increases `p` by a variable amount at a fixed frequency. 
Also, you need to remember to remove `task` (using `RemoveScheduledTask`) once you're done with it.

Comment: I think this is probably a good-enough approach. +1, thanks. I'll be waiting for other options for a while to accept. One could add the run and remove scheduled tasks in the second argument of the slider's dynamic, right? So that only when dragged the task exists

Comment: You could also create it once and use `StartScheduledTask` and `StopScheduledTask` in the second argument of `Dynamic` to start and stop it.

Comment: Makes sense. Create it in Initialization and remove it in Deinitialization

Answer (score 4):

Here's another way using `Refresh` that's perhaps a bit cleaner:

```
DynamicModule[{x = 0, y = 0},
    {Slider[Dynamic[x, {(x = #) &, (x = 0.) &}], {-1, 1}], 
     Dynamic[Refresh[y += x, TrackedSymbols :> {}, UpdateInterval -> 0.1]]}
]
```

Comment: +1. I took it and turned the second dynamic into the second argument of a DynamicWrapper so it becomes what I wanted: just a slider that does the updating. `DynamicWrapper[Slider..., Refresh[...]]`

Comment: This is way neater, but for some reason I don't understand, Heike's solution allows me to put lower update intervals before it gets way slower than it should

Comment: Interesting... didn't notice that

Comment: @Rojo, R.M: This is beautiful and elegant, nice use of `Refresh` & `DynamicWrapper`!